# C# Socket Programming: server does not accept client connections

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server

I am new to socket programming in C#. Have searched the web like crazy for the solution to my problem but didnt find anything that could fix it. So heres my problem:

I am trying to write a client-server application. For the time being, the server will also run on my local machine. The application transmits a byte stream of data from the client to the server. **The problem is that the server doesnt detect a client request for connection, while the client is able to connect and transmit the byte stream**.

here is the server code:

```
String strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
Console.WriteLine(strHostName);
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
soc.Bind(ipEnd);

Console.WriteLine("Web Server Running... Press ^C to Stop...");

Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartListen));
th.Start();
```

The StartListen thread is as below:

```
public void StartListen()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string message;
            Byte[] bSend = new Byte[1024];
            soc.Listen(100);

            if (soc.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nClient Connected!!\n==================\n CLient IP {0}\n", soc.RemoteEndPoint);
                Byte[] bReceive = new Byte[1024 * 5000];
                int i = soc.Receive(bReceive);
```

The client code is as follows:

```
hostIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(hostIPAddress,port);
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Server...");
clientSocket.Connect(ipEnd);
Console.WriteLine("Sending File...");
clientSocket.Send(clientData);
Console.WriteLine("Disconnecting...");
clientSocket.Close();
Console.WriteLine("File Transferred...");
```

Now what happens is that the server starts and when I run the client, it connects, sends and closes. But nothing happens on the server console, it doesnt detect any connection: **if (soc.Connected) remains false**.

I checked whether the server was listening to 127.0.0.1:5050 through netstat, and it sure was listening. Cant figure out the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side use [Socket.Accept Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.accept.aspx) to accept incoming connection. The method returns a `Socket` for a newly created connection: the `Send()` and `Receive()` methods can be used for this socket.

For example, after accepting the separate thread can be created to process the client connection (i.e. client session).

```
private void ClientSession(Socket clientSocket)
{
    // Handle client session:
    // Send/Receive the data.
}

public void Listen()
{
    Socket serverSocket = ...;

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
        var clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();

        Console.WriteLine("Client has been accepted!");
        var thread = new Thread(() => ClientSession(clientSocket))
            {
                IsBackground = true
            };
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshanArif, great. I've just added code to illustrate the approach.

Comment: i didnt down-vote, in fact, i tried to vote up, but it would allow...your answer is correct, its also helpful...

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshanArif, I didn't mean that it was you. It was someone else who didn't leave the comment (the reason of down-voting).